# Loop through a json using laravel/php

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, loops

I run function `DB::table('table_name')->get()` and `json_encode($posts)`get the result as `{{posts}}` which prints out:

```
[{"id":1,"author":"Laravel_Newbie","author_id":2,"posted_date":"2018-05-12 00:00:00","body":"Hello to Laravel!"},{"id":2,"author":"Other User","author_id":3,"posted_date":"2018-05-12 00:00:00","body":"Hello and an another body ."}]
```

Now, I need to show the information in a better way. So, How do I something like `

```
 <div>
   <b> author </b>
   <b> posted_date </b>
   <p> body </p>
 </div>
```

` and so on using the data from the database. So, How do I do that?

Comment: Json_decode your json string as array then you can loop through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php you can use $posts object to loop results and display them:

```
foreach($posts as $post){
    ?>
    <div>
      <b><?php echo $post->author; ?></b>
      <b><?php echo $post->posted_date; ?></b>
      <p><?php echo $post->body; ?></p>
   </div>

    <?php
}
```

Or you can loop it directly in JS, it depends on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

don't use `json_encode($posts)`
and try it (blade code)

```
@foreach($posts as $item)
    <div>
        <b> {{$item->author}} </b>
        <b> {{$item->posted_date}} </b>
        <p> {{$item->body}} </p>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks, but **.author** didn't work but **->author** did!